# How to show a PHP produced page on a cordova app using JSONP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova, jsonp

The basis of what I'm trying to do store paths in a mySQL then images on the server. Then using the PHP code below load them onto the screen and move through them using a button. This is fine on the browser. However these actions will actually be done on a cordova app which doesn't accept PHP and I can't use HTTP Request to carry out my functions. Could anyone help me convert my code and display my images. I think the best option would be to use JSONP or a combination of AJAX and JSONP.

Below is my code from the PHP side which I was trying to display using HTTP Request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

$select_query = "SELECT `ImagesPath` FROM `offerstbl` ORDER by `ImagesId` DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());   
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
$data[] = $row['ImagesPath'];
}

$images = json_encode($data);

?>

<script> 

var images = <?php echo $images; ?>
alert(images[1]);


var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = images[index];
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
}

function changeImage(){
var img = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
index++;
index = index % images.length; // This is for if this is the last image then goto first image
img.src = images[index];
}
</script>




<body onload="buildImage();">
<div class="contents" id="content"></div>
<button onclick="changeImage()">NextImage</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the HTML code in the cordova I've been using to display the PHP code. However none of my JavaScript functions work. I think it needs elements of JSONP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("phpFile").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http:server/content.php?");
    xmlhttp.send();

}


</head>

<body onload="showUser()">

<div class="contents" id="phpFile">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're running an app and not an actual browser, the same domain policy doesn't apply.

I had to specify inside the `config.xml` any URLs I wanted to access with the app.

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id = "io.something.something" version = "1.6">
     <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
     <access origin="https://mydomain.com" subdomains="true" />
</widget>
```

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: In the code above it has no problem running the html elements of the php file. So it isn't  a permissions issue. Thank you though. The issue no of the functions are running on the app. I added your code to my config file just in case though but still no joy.